# Request timeouts on creation of a simple model on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, request, timeout, request-timed-out

It's not really creation of a model, it seems more appropriate to say its the creation of a model record.

I have a Dish model that belongs_to User. When User logs in, they can add bank info (I'm using Stripe). If the bank info is added, they can add an Item. They can connect Instagram and I save the URL pointing to the image of the item as an attribute on the Item model.

When I use the app on my laptop, I can create Items no problem, they always work almost instantly. However on mobile (I started testing and I've had a lot of work to do to make it responsive, etc) I notice that when I "Create Item" it more often than not fails to complete the request, and while on my index.html.erb page I can see it (even if the request doesn't complete and a flash notice fails to appear on completion of the routing after the post request occurs).

I checked my logs and this is what appears:

```
2015-06-04T06:58:47.272355+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ItemsController#create as HTML
2015-06-04T06:58:47.272412+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"LzVBUKCq4jdN907WLQNrxEtBF0x+Dw+I6DKLjp9AsKA=", "dish"=>{"image_url"=>"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xpa1/t51.2885-15/e15/11192912_1613498252201707_300090299_n.jpg", "name"=>"Keurig Coffee", "description"=>"I hasve three flavors... surprise! ", "price"=>"2.0"}, "commit"=>"Create Item"}
2015-06-04T06:59:17.262061+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/dishes" host=trophus.herokuapp.com request_id=d164ec85-0c79-46ee-bed0-4b92db857f61 fwd="166.170.30.35" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=30010ms status=503 bytes=0
2015-06-04T07:00:05.685876+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 302 Found in 78412ms (ActiveRecord: 78219.6ms)
```

Comment: this seems to be an issue with your mobile data speed which is causing delay in the requests.

Comment: what is the server you are using?

Comment: The server I am using is puma